# How to echo specific mysql data in specific places using php?

Tags: mysql

If the 'SELECT' statement is used to select data from a database then how do we echo specific rows to specific places on a page using php?

To explain this better - I am trying to SELECT * ALL FROM a table but to echo multiple rows to particular places on the html page using php.

So, imagine that my entire mark up and css has 20 thumbnails on a page and each thumbnail has data and an image that is unique to each thumbnail....do I have to replicate the below 20 times?

I am thinking that the best way to do this (which is probably completely wrong) is to use this statement

SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID = 4 >>> i.e. where I'd like that specific data echoed....

So, if I have 20 thumbnails do I do this 20 times?

```
    <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID = 4;") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Product:</th> <td>".$info['product_name'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

And, rinse and repeat but I change the below statement each time for each thumbnail (each thumbnail has unique data that comes from each row on the MySQL)

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID = 4;
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Separate the model. Read all the data into an array - that is, put the SQL behind a function such that only the array of relevant data is returned. Then emit the appropriate HTML output for each array item, such as in a loop. Using `IN` may be appropriate here (specify the relevant IDs), if no other join will do - although another join or select will usually do if the images are part of a relevant container, such as a gallery or product listing. So no, you do everything *once*.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example.. First get the data with wanted ID:s. Create function for data request.

```
<?php 
     // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE ID IN (2,3,4,5,6);") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 

     // This holds all data rows
     $data_array = array(); 

     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
       $data_array[] = $data;

     // Function for rendering data to html 
     function getItemHtml($id) {

       $html = "";

       foreach($data_array as $row) {
          if ($row['ID'] == $id) {
            $html = "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
            // etc.. create item html here
            break;
          }
       }

       return $html;
     }

     // To create one item just call this with item id.

     echo getItemHtml(4); 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - quick question - why is the $html = "" empty?

Comment: It's just init code.. like if row whit passed id could not be found function returns empty string.